InvalidOperationException: The value of 'IdentityUserRole<Guid>.RoleId' is unknown when attempting to save changes in ASP.NET Core Identity
I'm encountering the following exception when trying to register a user and add them to a role in my ASP.NET Core application using Entity Framework Core and ASP.NET Identity:

System.InvalidOperationException: The value of 'IdentityUserRole.RoleId' is unknown when attempting to save changes. This is because the property is also part of a foreign key for which the principal entity in the relationship is not known.

I have this Register method
public async Task<OperationResult<RegisterResponseDto>> Register(RegisterBaseDto RegisterDto)
{
    var UserRole = await RoleManager.FindByIdAsync(RegisterDto.RoleId.ToString());
    if (UserRole == null) 
    {
        return OperationResult<RegisterResponseDto>.Failure("User Role Not Found.");
    }

    IdentityResult Result = null;
    AppUser? MappedUser = UserFactory.Create(UserRole, RegisterDto);

    if (MappedUser == null)
    {
        return OperationResult<RegisterResponseDto>.Failure("User Not Created.");
    }
    
    Result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(MappedUser, RegisterDto.Password);

    if (Result.Succeeded)
    {
        var mappedRegisterResponse = Mapper.Map<RegisterResponseDto>(MappedUser);
        var roleAssignmentResult = await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(MappedUser, UserRole.Name);

        if (roleAssignmentResult.Succeeded)
        {
            return OperationResult<RegisterResponseDto>.Success(mappedRegisterResponse);
        }
        else { 
            return OperationResult<RegisterResponseDto>.Failure("User is not created, Please try again.");
        }
    }
    return OperationResult<RegisterResponseDto>.Failure("User is not created, Please try again.");
}

Additional Information:

I am using ASP.NET Core 8 with Entity Framework Core and ASP.NET Identity.
The AppUser class inherits from IdentityUser.

The exception occurs when I attempt to call AddToRoleAsync.
What I’ve Tried:

Ensured that the role exists in the database before assigning it to the user.
Verified that the database context is correctly set up and that the IdentityUserRole is being configured properly.
Checked for potential issues with the entity relationships in my DbContext.


Does the roleId really exist in database table?

What happens in UserFactory.Create?
